# Reordering columns in ggplot2, Error: Mapping should be created with `aes() or `aes_()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to reorder my columns in ggplot, to go from min to max, but keep getting this error message

```
countries<-c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Denmark", "France" ,"Germany", "Italy","Luxembourg" ,"Netherlands","Norway", "New Zealand","Spain","Sweden","United Kingdom","USA")
cost<-c(1221,711,184,250,6658,51,1118,880,919,2500,1558,2452,103,920,1460,401)
citcost<-data.frame(countries, cost)

citcost %>% ggplot(citcost, aes(x=reorder(countries, cost), y=cost, fill=countries)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + scale_colour_brewer()
```

Error: Mapping should be created with `aes() or` aes_()`.

Comment: You don't need `citcost` again in `ggplot`

Comment: i.e. just do `citcost %>% ggplot(aes(x=reorder(countries, cost), y=cost, fill=countries)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + scale_colour_brewer()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the arguments of `ggplot`.  Here, the second argument is `mapping` and it expects `aes`, instead we are providing the data object with `ggplot(citcost`) while the data is already passed in via `cicost %>% ggplot`.  Thus, the `ggplot`, call in the OP's code is

```
ggplot(data = citcost, mapping = citcost, ...)
```

Instead it would be

```
citcost %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=reorder(countries, cost), y=cost, fill=countries)) + 
       geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
       scale_colour_brewer()
```

-output

[image]